# Javascript href navigate to a different url not owned by me then scroll to a class automatically

Tags: javascript, html, url, href

So basically I want to create an href like this  `<a href="https://www.some-website-i-do-not-own.com >Go to link and jump to class</a>` and it will link out to an external site that I do not own but I know on the bottom of that page there is a div with a class that I found in the DOM linking to an article. I want to not only redirect to this page but automatically have the browser scroll to that Y position for that div's class.

Again I do not have access to any of their code I found this class throguh the DOM, is this possible  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's usually done by adding

**#id-of-element-to-scroll-to**

to the end of the URL
take [that](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Stack_Overflow#Statistics) for example

```
https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Stack_Overflow#Statistics
```

will redirect you to their page, and scroll to the element with id="Statistics"

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to go to a website's page specific location with IDs. If you know the ID of an element, located where you want to jump to, you just add it at the end of the URL like this:
`<a href="https://www.some-website-i-do-not-own.com**#bottom**>Go to link and jump to class</a>`

The ID is being started with a *#* and then the name of the element's id.
If I helped you, you can approve the question as a solution.
Have a nice day ;)